# Support multiple browser/tab session J2EE/Web Application

Tags: java, session, web-applications, browser, jakarta-ee

Because of Inherent property of Web Browsers, that when done in some ways e.g. Ctrl + N, it open new window with session id.
This behaviour would effect a web application as normally a web application would do request.getSession()
and in the above scenario, the sessions would get mixed up.

Would would be the good way to get out of such situations? (Other than tell users not tell do Ctrl + N :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest solution is MyFaces orchestra. It allows conversation and window management for JSF.

The upcoming spring release (3.1) is supposed to have support for this (in spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks! can you please also suggest a different way(instead of introducing a new framework).

Comment: @Sandeep Jindal it is non-trivial. You can take a look at the current spring codebase, it should have some preliminary implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Some web frameworks have explicit support for multiple browser window flows.

E.g. [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) has the [INewBrowserWindowListener](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/INewBrowserWindowListener.html) interface to implement this functionality. Wicket keeps separate page flows for the different browser windows, isolating their states from each other.

Comment: @Bezho Thanks for suggesting the frameworks. Can you also please suggest the fundamental/idea behind how to do that (e.g. could it be done using some property of browsers,or going some other trick like [ping](http://www.emerle.net/post/2010/02/02/An-Approach-to-Multiple-Browser-Session-Detection.aspx)